# Xcode/iOS5: Show UIDatePicker when UITextField is pressed (+ hide default keyboard)

Tags: xcode, uitextfield, ios5, uidatepicker

I'd like to call UIDatePicker only when UITextField is active. When the date is picked, it should be shown in the same UITextField.

I even don't know how to call the Picker.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is a delegate method called

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField*)textField
{
[textField resignFirstResponder];
 in this you have to do this
pick = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
[pick setFrame:CGRectMake(0,200,320,120)];
[pick addTarget:self action:@selector(done) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]
[self.view addSubview:pick];
}
```

in

```
-(void)done
{
[textfield setText:pick.date];
}
```

release the pick in dealloc

Comment: Don't forget to release pick.

Comment: Thank you Hitman. But I get the error: Use of undeclared identifier 'pick'.

Comment: UIDatePicker *pick write this in the .h file

Comment: Okay. But now in -(void)done is an error: Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSDate *' to parameter of type 'NSString *'.

Comment: Take the NSDateFormatter by using this you can convert the NSDate to NSString.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Hitman's answer, I think you should implement the

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

instead and return NO. Then show the date picker and fill the UITextField text according to the picker selection.

Comment: Thanks jbat :) But I get the error: Use of undeclared identifier 'pick'.

Comment: Just create an ivar (instance variable), declaring the pick (UIDatePicker* pick;) in your header (and make a retain property). This way you can keep a reference to it, to remove it from the view when the user is done.

Comment: Okay. But now in -(void)done is an error: Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSDate *' to parameter of type 'NSString *'.

Comment: You need to convert the NSDate (pick.date) to a string (using NSDateFormatter) then assign that string to the textfield.text.

Comment: I tried it before: The picker appears now on every textField and does not disappear anymore..

Comment: then remove it from the view ([pick removeFromSuperview]).